# How to compress blend file for blend stack exchange?

Tags: compression

i'm trying to upload files to blender stack exchange (BSE) to ask other question but BSE can only upload 30MB. screenshot is not so great because node shading is too big

what i have tried but none work:
save as blend compression file (not significant)
delete all irrelevant object and materials
remove modifier and applied decimate modifier to reduce vertices
append the relevant problem to new blend file and save as new
compress it to zip file

Answer (score 2):

After deleting all unnecessary data in the blend file, try all 6 options in under `File` menu -> `Clean Up` and try deleting `Orphan Data` in the `Outliner`. Alternatively you can upload your files on `Dropbox` or `Google Drive` and publicly share the files.

[image]